# Daemon blocks remaining, Daemon is syncing but nothing happening?

Tags: daemon

Finally I have created my Monero wallet, however syncing is going on forever, there is nothing happening. Is this normal?

Comment: Please update the question with your operating system, version and type of wallet, local or remote daemon etc etc.

Comment: 64 bit operating system  x64 bit processor   windows 10 home   vers 1909

Comment: wallet ledger nano x

Comment: @sinjen1 - Have you already tried using a remote node?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main possible bottlenecks: your internet and you disk speed.

Check how loaded your disk. If it's HDD and most time load nearby full, you can try to download blockchain on SSD (after that you can move it to HDD because you'll not download entire blockchain so it won't take as many time as first).

Comment: Its not my HDD because I only have SSD,so must be my internet connection.